# Is there a tool/website to see which non-Latin words are derived from a given Latin word?

Tags: etymology, derivation, resource-request

One way I use to learn Latin vocabulary is to seek for derived Spanish/English words which meaning I know. For instance, *[gressus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gressus)* derived into *[egresar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egresar)* and *[ingresar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingresar)*, Spanish words which mean to exit ("*e[x] gressus*") and to enter ("*in gressus*"), respectively.

In this spirit, when I face a new Latin word, oftentimes I want to find Spanish/English derivatives, but I lack a systematic tool to do this. Wiktionary does offer this for some words but it is very far from systematic. The entry for *gressus*, for example, lacks this.

Are you aware of any tool, dictionary or website that offers this information in a systematic way?

Comment: Try this: https://archive.org/details/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft/page/n5

Comment: @fdb Do you mind turning that into an answer?